# Django -- Password Clean fails when min_length is set

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a user registration form that has a "password" and "confirm password" field. When I add "min_length" to my password field and then run the submitted data through my custom clean_confirm_password method, it gives a "Key Error / Password" error.

This occurs when the password field is less than 5 characters, whether the confirm_password field matches or not.

I have tried adding "min_length" to "confirm_password,"  but still get the same error.

Everything works fine when I remove "min_length" totally.

Any help is appreciated!

My forms.py file:

```
class NewUser(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=75)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=45)
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

    def clean_confirm_password(self):
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        original_password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        if original_password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password doesn't match")

        return confirm_password
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit a password with fewer than 5 characters, it fails the `min_length` validation so `password` is not in your form's `cleaned_data` dictionary. When you try to access the missing key, you get a `KeyError`.

Instead, you should try:

```
original_password = self.cleaned_data.get('password', '')
```

which will return `''` if the password is too short.

As an aside, a `clean_myfieldname` method should only rely on one field. If you want to clean and validate fields that rely on each other, use the `clean` method for this (see the [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)).

Comment: This worked like a champ! Also, thanks for pointing out the `clean` method. I've made changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When you access `self.cleaned_data`, the form validates all of its fields, which would cause the password field to be validated against its `min_length` argument.

Comment: Sorry. I see now my question wasn't entirely clear. I want the password field to validate as you described, but instead of coming back with my error message, it gives the Key Error. So if I enter 3 digits in the password field, and any password in the confirm password field (matching or not), instead of giving me the "Not enough characters" error, it throws a Key Error.